# How do you send a dataframe to a specific cell on a spreadsheet so that it can run through excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Title may be a bit confusing sorry pretty bad wording but an example should be easier to understand

Ex) Lets say this image is my dataframe.

[image]

and I want the data inside my dataframe to run through an update command that is in my excel
which could be as follows in this image:

[image]

How would I go about this. I believe the .iloc command is needed but I'm not too good at implementing this.

EDIT:
[This would be my 2nd dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmemn.png)
The desired output would be the first dataframe but what I want to do is run the first dataframe through an update command to update the 2nd dataframe

Comment: and would you show the desired output as well please?

Comment: You want to concatinate all values in a row or what ?

Comment: In the commands which are in the excel sheet they are just update commands to update another excel so like lets say there was another dataframe with similar columns, it would update the row so for example the other dataframe might have apple red cat but then it would update to apple red frog

Comment: @SillyStraw1022 CONCAT function joins multiple strings in to one, it doesn't update anything. You can simply make desired daatframe and with it overwrite your excel files.

Comment: @Degas Miksenas Yeah this is correct it was just an example since I needed to do an insert one as well which the insert would use concat